# filter spark dataframe with row field that is an array of strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Spark 1.5 and Scala 2.10.6

I'm trying to filter a dataframe via a field "tags" that is an array of strings.  Looking for all rows that have the tag 'private'.

```
val report = df.select("*")
  .where(df("tags").contains("private"))
```

getting:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve 'Contains(tags, private)' due to data type mismatch:
>   argument 1 requires string type, however, 'tags' is of array
>   type.;

Is the filter method better suited?

UPDATED:

the data is coming from cassandra adapter but a minimal example that shows what I'm trying to do and also gets the above error is:

```
  def testData (sc: SparkContext): DataFrame = {
    val stringRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("""
      { "name": "ed",
        "tags": ["red", "private"]
      }""",
      """{ "name": "fred",
        "tags": ["public", "blue"]
      }""")
    )
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    sqlContext.read.json(stringRDD)
  }
  def run(sc: SparkContext) {
    val df1 = testData(sc)
    df1.show()
    val report = df1.select("*")
      .where(df1("tags").contains("private"))
    report.show()
  }
```

UPDATED: the tags array can be any length and the 'private' tag can be in any position

UPDATED: one solution that works: UDF

```
val filterPriv = udf {(tags: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => tags.contains("private")}
val report = df1.filter(filterPriv(df1("tags")))
```

Comment: post sample of your data and how u r creating the df

Comment: One option is to build a UDF.

Comment: Well, after looking at the source code (since the scaladoc for `Column.contains` says only "Contains the other element" which is not very enlightening), I see that `Column.contains` constructs an instance of `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Contains` which says "A function that returns true if the string `left` contains the string `right`". So it seems that `df1("tags").contains` cannot do what we want it to do in this case. I don't know what alternative to suggest. There is an `ArrayContains` also in `...expressions` but `Column` doesn't seem to make use of it.

Comment: Indeed, after changing the data to just strings instead of an array of strings, I find that the query succeeds.

Comment: @DavidMaust, I got a UDF to work:
`val filterPriv = udf {(tags: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => tags.contains("private")}; val report = df1.filter(filterPriv(df1("tags")))`
still looking for something nicer but at least I'm not blocked.  thx!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think if you use `where(array_contains(...))` it will work. Here's my result:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> def testData (sc: SparkContext): DataFrame = {
     |     val stringRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq
     |      ("""{ "name": "ned", "tags": ["blue", "big", "private"] }""",
     |       """{ "name": "albert", "tags": ["private", "lumpy"] }""",
     |       """{ "name": "zed", "tags": ["big", "private", "square"] }""",
     |       """{ "name": "jed", "tags": ["green", "small", "round"] }""",
     |       """{ "name": "ed", "tags": ["red", "private"] }""",
     |       """{ "name": "fred", "tags": ["public", "blue"] }"""))
     |     val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
     |     import sqlContext.implicits._
     |     sqlContext.read.json(stringRDD)
     |   }
testData: (sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala>   
     | val df = testData (sc)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, tags: array<string>]

scala> val report = df.select ("*").where (array_contains (df("tags"), "private"))
report: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, tags: array<string>]

scala> report.show
+------+--------------------+
|  name|                tags|
+------+--------------------+
|   ned|[blue, big, private]|
|albert|    [private, lumpy]|
|   zed|[big, private, sq...|
|    ed|      [red, private]|
+------+--------------------+
```

Note that it works if you write `where(array_contains(df("tags"), "private"))`, but if you write `where(df("tags").array_contains("private"))` (more directly analogous to what you wrote originally) it fails with `array_contains is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column`. Looking at the source code for `Column`, I see there's some stuff to handle `contains` (constructing a `Contains` instance for that) but not `array_contains`. Maybe that's an oversight.

Comment: `.select("*")` is not needed => `df.where(...) ...`

Comment: Need to `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_contains` before one can use this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ordinal to refer to the json array's for e.g. in your case `df("tags")(0)`. Here is a working sample

```
scala> val stringRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("""
     |       { "name": "ed",
     |         "tags": ["private"]
     |       }""",
     |       """{ "name": "fred",
     |         "tags": ["public"]
     |       }""")
     |     )
stringRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[87] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> sqlContext.read.json(stringRDD)
res28: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, tags: array<string>]

scala> val df=sqlContext.read.json(stringRDD)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, tags: array<string>]

scala> df.columns
res29: Array[String] = Array(name, tags)

scala> df.dtypes
res30: Array[(String, String)] = Array((name,StringType), (tags,ArrayType(StringType,true)))

scala> val report = df.select("*").where(df("tags")(0).contains("private"))
report: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, tags: array<string>]

scala> report.show
+----+-------------+
|name|         tags|
+----+-------------+
|  ed|List(private)|
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: thanks.  works if pos is fixed but it isn't.  I should have made the test data a little more complex, there can be any number of tags in the array, position is arbitrary.

Comment: @navicore then your code should work. check my update

Comment: interesting, I'm missing something, looks like exactly what I was doing but getting the error for.  double checking spark versions now...

Comment: @navicore this is on 1.5.4

Comment: thx.  I must be crossing hands somewhere.  I tried 1.5.1 and 1.6 and `val report = df.select("*").where(df("tags").contains("private"))` gives me that error in the orig post.  digging...

Comment: @navicore I cut and paste your code and I'm still getting the error reported by OP for `report = df.select("*").where(df("tags").contains("private"))`. I'm working on 1.5.1. I also looked at current (circa 1.6.0) source code and it appears the `Contains` class can only handle strings. I don't understand how it works for you -- can you explain it? Sorry for the bother.

Comment: @navicore my bad. I just realized i am printing the df and not report. I am not at my laptop will fix my edit later